# jquery .submit doesn't get called first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

The `.submit()` doesn't get called the first time the form is submitted. Once the create action fails and the user is redirected back to the page, if the submit button is clicked, the function gets called. I threw a debugger into `setUpForm()` and it does not get triggered the first time the page is loaded and form submitted.

The second issue is `.animate` is no longer working. It was, but then just stopped. Here is the code

**purchase.js**

```
$(function(){
    Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name = "stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
    setUpForm();


        function setUpForm(){ $('#new_purchase').submit(function(){
            $('input[type= submit]').attr('disabled',true);
            processCard();
            return false
    });
}

 function processCard() {
        var card = {
            number : $("#card_number").val(),
            cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
            expMonth: $('#card_month').val(),
            expYear : $('#card_year').val()
        };
        Stripe.createToken(card, handleStripeResponse); 
    }

   var handleStripeResponse = function(status, response){
        if (response.error)
            {
                var originalColor = $('#stripe_error').css('background')
                $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show();
                $('#stripe_error').animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFF00"}, 1000, function(){
                    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: originalColor}, 1000);
                });
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
        // alert(response.error.message);

        }
  else
  {
        // alert(response.id);
    $('#purchase_stripe_customer_token').val(response.id)
        $('#new_purchase')[0].submit()
  }
 }
 });
```

**ny.html.erb**

```
<div class = "uk-width-4-6 greeting_div">

    <div class = "img_div"><img class="trip_page" src= <%= asset_path('top_empire.JPG') %>></div>
    <h1 class= "greetings"> Greetings from: </h6>


</div>

<div class = "uk-width-2-6 greeting_div_2">
    <img class= "stamp" src = <%= asset_path('us_stamp.jpg') %> >
    <div class= "trip_information">
        <p>To: <%=@purchase.trip.location %></p><br>

        <p>From: <%=@purchase.trip.cost%> for 10 days</p>
        <div class = "uk-form"> <%= render 'layouts/form' %></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**_form_html.erb**

```
 <br>
        <legend> Buy Now! </legend>
       <%= form_for(@purchase, :method => :post) do |f| %>
        <% if @purchase.errors.any? %>
        <div class="error_messages">
            <ul>
                <%= @purchase.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
                    <li> <%= error %> <li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <%end%>

        <%= f.hidden_field :trip_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_customer_token %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :value_of_trip, value: "#{@purchase.trip.cost}"%>

        <% if @purchase.stripe_customer_token.present? %>
            <p> Your card has been provided <p>
        <% else %>
        <div id="stripe_error">
                    <noscript> Javascript must be enabled to use this form </noscript>  

            </div></br> 
                <div class = "uk-form-row">
                    <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
                    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
                </div>
                <div class = "uk-form-row">
                    <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code" %>
                    <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
                </div>
                <div class = "uk-form-row">
                    <%= label_tag :card_month, "Credit Expiration"   %>
                   <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
              <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
                <div><br>
        <% end %>
            <div class = "uk-form-row submit">
                <%= f.submit "Purchase" %>
            </div>
    <% end %>
```

**source**

```
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/uikit.almost-flat.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/uikit.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/home_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/purchases.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/form.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/purchases.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/uikit.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle. It would be very easy to debug jsfiddle.net

Comment: the animate issue is solved- thanks for the tip with jsfiddle, took about 2 seconds. For the `.submit` issue, the event is not binding until after the first submit fails and the browser is redirected back to the page.

Comment: The whole `$(function()` is not being called on the original page load actuall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Turbolinks**

It sounds like a problem with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)

Basically, Turbolinks makes Rails pages load quicker by keeping the `<head>` code constant, changing the `<body>` with ajax. The issue is this makes your standard JS think the page hasn't changed, consequently only working after refresh

There are two ways to fix Turbolinks problems:

> 1. Delegate
> 2. Use Turbolinks `page:load` & `page:change`

---

**Delegate**

If you want to bind to the `submit` event, you'd be best `delegating` from the `document` object (which doesn't change):

```
$(document).on("submit", "#new_purchase", function() {
  //submit code
});
```

---

**Events**

There are [two Turbolinks events called `page:load` and `page:change`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) which will help you tremendously:

```
$(document).ready(your_function);
$(document).on('page:load', your_function);
$(document).on('page:change', your_function);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your script on form submit checks Credit Card data, and after succesfull verification whole form is submitted again

modify your setupForm method:

```
/**
 * Simulate form submit with click on submit button
 */
$('input[type= submit]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    processCard();
});
```

and callback

```
var handleStripeResponse = function (status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        var originalColor = $('#stripe_error').css('background')
        $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show();
        $('#stripe_error').animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FFFF00"
        }, 1000, function () {
            $(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: originalColor
            }, 1000);
        });
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
        // alert(response.error.message);

    } else {
        // alert(response.id);
        $('#purchase_stripe_customer_token').val(response.id)
        /**
         * Trigger submit on form after succesfull validation
         */
        $('#new_purchase').trigger('submit');
    }
}
```